# Cannot set form width below certain value when FormBorderStyle is set to Sizable or to None

Tags: c#, winforms

.NET 4.7, WinForms.

I want to create a small border-less window, I set `FormBorderStyle` to `None` and set the width = 50, and the height = 50. It seems that there is some kind of minimum width (it looks about 150) and I cannot set a width smaller than that. As a result, the window looks like a long rectangle.

The left is the designer, the right is the window when executed.

[image: screen]

I changed the style to `Sizable`, and tried to resize the window. It seemed that I can set the height almost to 0, but I could not set the width lower than the minimum above.

How can I make a borderless 50 * 50 form?

Comment: Thank you for pointing the old question. Not an exact duplicate (the old question was about Height, mine is about Width) but the solution could be applied to both of the problems, so I clicked "It solved my problem".